# MySQL Query, two tables joining and using

Tags: mysql

Alright so I’m using MySQL and I have gotten a database that is supposed to be for news articles and in the database I have two tables, one is employees and the other articles.
Table employees consist of employee ID and name etc. and table articles has article ID and information about the articles.
Now what I want to do is, I would like to get all of the employees even those who have not written any articles. I would like to get out the employees and what article ID they have been in. 
For example:

```
employeeID  | Name     |  articleID
1           | Loren    |  26  
2           | Jack     |  22
2           | Jack     |  23
5           | Clark    |  25
5           | Clark    |  26
5           | Clark    |  27
2           | Loren    |  28
2           | Louise   |  30
2           | Louise   |  31
2           | Louise   |  33
```

Now here is where I think it’s getting tricky, I can’t get my head around it, I’m supposed to make a join to get both of the tables come together, and then use count to get out how many articles an employee has written. 
So while using two queries

```
SELECT Name, employeeID  
FROM employees

SELECT articleID
FROM articles
```

I get out the information I need, but how can I assemble these two queries into one so I get it out from the example above

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want to get the articleIDs and also a count of the articles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be left outer join

```
SELECT e.Name, e.employeeID, COUNT(a.ArticleID) FROM Employees e
LEFT OUTER JOIN Articles a ON a.employeeID = e.employeeID
GROUP BY e.employeeID
```

you can check the working example through [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04ee5/2).

Comment: Alright, so actually thanks for the reply I was having a little struggle trying to figure out what kind of join I actually should use so thanks for throwing me in the right direction when it comes to that. Your code also helped me to solve my problem,  so now finally I can get my information :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is an employeeID on articles

```
SELECT e.name, e.employeeID, count(*) 
FROM employees e
JOIN articles a on a.employeeID = a.employeeID
GROUP BY (e.name, e.employeeID)
```

I haven't checked this but this is the general idea. There are lots of SQL tutorials available online

Answer (score 0):

`articleID` needs something to `JOIN` on. Let's say you also have an `employeeID` in the same table you have `articleID`. Your `JOIN` could look as simple as:

```
$mySQLi->query("SELECT e.Name,e.employeeID,a.articleID FROM employees e,articles a WHERE e.employeeID = a.employeeID");
```

Note: `$mySQLi` is `new mysqli()` with the correct arguments.